# Where do resource files go during Swift development?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, resources, bundle

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bang.wav", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
```

I found this nice example code for playing a sound.  Question not answered there: where does bang.wav need to be located in order to be found by Bundle.main.path during development and debugging?  If MacOS and iOS answers are different, both are of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundle resources are located in `/Contents/Resources` and can be included in subdirectories as well. The function `.path(forResource:)` automatically finds it for you.

As long as your file is drag-dropped in your Xcode project, a Build Phase entry will be added that automatically copies your file to the bundle Resource folder.